# Duplicates when inserting into std::set<std::tuple<std::string, ...>>

Tags: c++, c++11

I tried to use std::tuple as an element of std::set where std tuple consists of std::string and a bool (for this example only, in normal use case the tuple consists of 3 elements). The string of the tuple shall be unique, therefore I created comparator that would sort the elements on the first element of the tuple. However, when inserting into aforementioned set I do get duplicate elements in the container. I cannot see where I am making a mistake. Thanks in advance for suggestions!

```
#include <set>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    using tuple_t = std::tuple<std::string, bool>;
    std::function<bool(const tuple_t &, const tuple_t &)> tupleCmp =
            [](const tuple_t & l, const tuple_t & r) -> bool {
                return static_cast<bool>(std::get<0>(l).compare(std::get<0>(r)));
            };

    set<tuple_t, decltype(tupleCmp)> s(tupleCmp);
    s.insert(make_tuple("ahoy", false));
    s.insert(make_tuple("this", false));
    s.insert(make_tuple("creates", false));
    s.insert(make_tuple("duplicates", false));
    s.insert(make_tuple("ahoy", false));

    for (const auto & i :  s){
        cout << get<0>(i) << endl;
    }
    auto debug_stop = 0;
}
```

[Debugger snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QvfEG.png)

```
Output:
ahoy
duplicates
creates
this
ahoy
```

Comment: I think your code has undefined behaviour, because `tupleCmp` doesn't create a strict weak ordering as required for [compare](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare). A `std::set`'s comparator is not supposed to check for equality, but imply order. It's return value must indicate wether `l < r` or not.

Comment: Thank you @churill, I must have misinterpreted "comp" of the set constructor docs. `return static_cast<bool>(std::get<0>(l)<(std::get<0>(r)));` works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::string::compare` returns `int` (neg, 0, positive) not `bool` (less than),

you want

```
std::get<0>(l).compare(std::get<0>(r)) < 0;
```

or

```
std::get<0>(l) < std::get<0>(r);
```

Answer (score 1):

`a.compare(b)` returns:

```
0          when the strings are equal
negative   when a comes before b  (ie a < b)
positive   when b comes before a  (ie b < a)
```

However, the comparators return value is converted to a `bool` and anything but `0` is converted to `true`, hence your comparator considers `a < b` to be `true` for any `a` and `b` unless `a == b`. In particular `a < b` is `true` and `b < a` is considered as `true` as well. This is not in accordance with the requirement of a [strict weak ordering](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare) and causes undefined behavior. You can use the "normal" `<` to compare the strings.

Comment: Hmm, there is a gap in my knowledge. I'd swear before testing it out that static_cast<bool>(-1) would produce false (It produces true as you pointed out). https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion. (Boolean conversions section)

Comment: @Godzilla consider that `std::string::compare` mimics Cs `strcmp` and in the early days C had no `bool`. I guess if C++ had three way comparison from the start `std::string::compare` would not exist